# Custom control for flickr is not works on the production server but it works on the development server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webrequest

We developed a site named donmueang.com; this site contains two custom controls named Youtube control and flickr control. Our problem is this two custom controls runs well on the development server but only flickr control does not work on the production server.

What would be the actual problem?

Comment: *Not working* is a phrase commonly employed by people who don't know or don't care about how a computer works. This phrase is totally inappropriate for a software developer. You will need to provide much more details about those controls, how are they implemented, show some source code, explain what is the expected result and how the actual result on the production server differs from this expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It has to do with where the Flickr API tries to store it's cache. By default it tries to create a directory and store a file in the currently logged in user's ApplicationData folder. Since most production servers will not grant access from your application to this folder, the Flickr API will not load correctly.

The fix for me, since I'm using the ASP.NET Flickr API, was to add an entry to the web.config file:

`<flickrNet cacheLocation="E:\inetpub\[MyWebAppDirectory]\flickr_cache\"></flickrNet>`

Hope this helps.